# Como verificar se o nome de um arquivo tem 16 dígitos?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, diretório

```
namespace _06_Teste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdValidar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles("c:\\ImgRoute\\Caixa9 D1\\", "*.*"))
            {
                FileInfo fileName = new FileInfo(file);

                string imag = fileName.Name;

                if (imag.Length == 16)
                {
                    //("Numero do auto correto");
                }
                else
                {
                    //("Numero do auto invalido");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Armanda, editei a seu pergunta de forma que penso ficar melhor. Seria necessário, no entanto, você explicar qual é o problema que encontra com o seu código.

Comment: O código não esta rodando. E gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de exibir o erro caso o nome do arquivo não tenha 16 digitos.

Comment: @Amanda você tem que dizer o que está acontecendo. Dá erro? Qual? Dá um resultado indesejado? Qual seria o esperado? Edite a pergunta e dê detalhes, nós não conseguimos adivinhar qual é o seu problema. O que é o nome do arquivo? É só o nome sem a extensão? Com? Com o *path* completo? Quando se desenvolve software devemos ser detalhistas.

Answer (score 3):

Acrescente **using** no início do arquivo:

```
using System.IO;
```

Exemplo:

```
using System.IO;

namespace _06_Teste
{
    ......
    Directory.GetFiles(....)
    FileInfo fileName = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
```

ou faça a chamada das funçõs usando o caminho completo

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(....)
System.IO.FileInfo fileName = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
```

Comment: Esse código não faz nada, a pessoa quer saber se o nome do arquivo tem 16 dígitos esse código nem pega o nome do arquivo. A função [`Path.GetFileWithoutExtension(String)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetFileNameWithoutExtension_System_String_) necessária para realizar a tarefa de retornar o nome do arquivo sem a extensão nem foi mencionada. A estrutura `System.IO.FileInfo` tem o campo `Name` que retorna o nome arquivo com a extensão.

Comment: Na época da pergunta, notei que a pessoa fazia a verificação `if (imag.Length == 16)` , mas tinha esquecido de colocar o `using System.IO;` Entendi que ela fazendo isto, o código dela funcionaria como ela esperava. Obviamente o código precisa ser melhorado. Mas o usuário não deu mais retorno aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que esteja tentando pegar o nome do arquivo sem extensão então deve usar o método [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_GetFileNameWithoutExtension_System_String_). Eu edito se der mais detalhes.

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\ImgRoute\Caixa9 D1\", "*.*")) {
    var imagem = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    if (imagem.Length == 16) {
        //("Numero do auto correto");
    } else {
        //("Numero do auto invalido");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetFilesInDir.cs).

Se quiser com a extensão deve usar o método [`GetFileName`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_GetFileName_System_String_).

Eu prefiro usar [`Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\ImgRoute\\Caixa9 D1\\", "*.*")`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) se estiver usando o .NET 4 em diante. Ele é mais rápido.